# Separating text data set based on content in R

Tags: r

Can anyone help me in separating a text data set with respect to the content in R. eg: Issue with product - to a product subset, issue with delivery - move it to delivery subset

Comment: You're going to get much better answers if you can provide some sample data and output.

Comment: We can't help unless you provide some code. Give an example of the data and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I do not have the code yet, however, this is an example:  I have sent u an email but till now I have not received any reply. (Issue with customer service);  I have not received my ordered item which was to be delivered on 16th. (issue with delivery). Both are in the same text file and I want to separate it based on the content

Comment: Any idea on how to do it. I am new to R and trying to get this done. Appreciate you help.

Comment: I tried to run this, but got error- testdata1 <- testdata %>% filter(str_detect(text, c("product", "products", "received", "defective","seller","fake")))